# How to make auto-balancing content columns with CSS Grids

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

So this is a layout I have lusted over basically for the last 20 years - the ability to have a list of content which auto-flows between two columns newspaper style.  There have been many hacks over the years, involving back-end or front-end code, but nothing CSS based with semantic markup.

I'm just starting to dive into CSS Grids as I feel the browser support is finally enough, but I can't figure out how to achieve what I want, even with the "most advanced grid system ever for CSS" as it's often touted.

So first of all let me share what I have done so far and semantically, this is the ideal markup:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.two-col-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [left] 1fr [right] 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-col-grid">
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section1">Section 1</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article9" class="article-list-link">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article10" class="article-list-link">Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="/hc/en-us/sections/360002655674-Track-my-payment" class="see-all-articles">
  See all 21 articles
</a>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section2">Section 2</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section3">Section 3</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section4">Section 4</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article9" class="article-list-link">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section5">Section 5</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

As I only defined two columns, I was hoping it would be as simple as that.  However, the content is flowing in rows which wrap as necessary and each wrap creates implicit grid rows which I didn't define.  Basically, this is what I could easily create with Flexbox and I thought CSS Grids was supposed to offer a lot more control.

In summary, my code does this:

[image]

But what I want it to do is this:

[image]

Comment: you need `columns`

Comment: can you elaborate @TemaniAfif?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: Indeed, your desired result is clearly **not a grid**.

Comment: @Paulie_D - 2 boxes side-by-side is most definitely a grid, by any definition.

Comment: No it's not - its two columns. A grid has equal rows in both columns which yours does not

Comment: @Paulie_D First of all, the Oxford definition of grid is "A network of lines that cross each other to form a series of squares or rectangles." and two rectangles definitely fits that definition and second of all, I never said my goal was to make a grid.  I very clearly said, my goal was to make a two-column auto-balancing layout using the CSS Grids syntax.  So please take your weak trolling somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Try columns css only

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.two-col-grid {
  columns: 2 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-col-grid">
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section1">Section 1</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article9" class="article-list-link">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article10" class="article-list-link">Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="/hc/en-us/sections/360002655674-Track-my-payment" class="see-all-articles">
  See all 21 articles
</a>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section2">Section 2</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section3">Section 3</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section4">Section 4</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article9" class="article-list-link">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section5">Section 5</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it with column-counter property (or using flexbox):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.two-col-grid {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-col-grid">
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section1">Section 1</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article9" class="article-list-link">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article10" class="article-list-link">Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="/hc/en-us/sections/360002655674-Track-my-payment" class="see-all-articles">
  See all 21 articles
</a>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section2">Section 2</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section3">Section 3</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section4">Section 4</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article9" class="article-list-link">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-item">
<h3 class="section-tree-title">
  <a href="/section5">Section 5</a>
</h3>

<ul class="article-list">
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article1" class="article-list-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article2" class="article-list-link">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article3" class="article-list-link">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article4" class="article-list-link">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article6" class="article-list-link">Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article7" class="article-list-link">Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="article-list-item">
    <a href="/article8" class="article-list-link">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Note flexbox will require a fixed height to enable wrapping.